# #name? error on EXCEL when copying and pasting data from MYSQL

Tags: mysql, excel

After copying the result table from MYSQL, I pasted it onto an excel sheet.

One of the columns have entries like -a, -b, -c, etc.

So excel thinks that it is a formula and then creates a #NAME? error.

Any suggestions on how i can avoid this error message, and have my column entries as it were in MYSQL?

Comment: You could modify your SQL query to not output such troublesome data.  Can you show us the query?

Answer (score 0):

You have couple of options here.

**1.** Either update your query in mysql so that you do not get `-` sign in the column by writing something like:

```
SELECT REPLACE( Column_Name, '-', '' ) AS Column_Name FROM Table_Name
```

**2.** Or you can work on this after pasting data in excel.

If you are using Excel 2013, use `=MID(FORMULATEXT(A1),2,LEN(FORMULATEXT(A1)))` considering your `Column A` contains "-a,-b,-c,..." and copy it down. `FORMULATEXT` is built-in function in Excel 2013.

If you are using older version of Excel you can do this by writing a UDF as:

```
Function FormulaText(rng As Range) As String
    FormulaText = rng.Formula
End Function
```

and then using this UDF as

```
=MID(FormulaText(A1),2,LEN(FormulaText(A1)))
```

You can then replace this column to column A (or which ever column contains data with `-` in the beginning).

Answer (score 0):

A way to get around this issue would to be have the following SQl query

Select concat("'", column1, "'")
From table1
;

Then copy and paste the result onto excel.